# why do I get a different MAC address using arp and ifconfig?

Tags: mac-address, ifconfig, arp

```
# ifconfig
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:8c:10:xx:xx
# arp
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.xxx.x.x              ether   38:72:c0:cc:xx:xx   C                     ethx
```

How come it shows different MAC addresses?

EDIT: btw, the one shown by `ifconfig` is the right one because it is the one that I see on my router

Comment: Your question does not show in any way that those different addresses belong to the same interface or the same IP addr. **Stop being paranoid and editing out information that is important to the question.**

Comment: @grawity i am not sure i am catching you drift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ifconfig provides the MAC address of your network interface, while arp provides the MAC address of other hardware on the network, such as your router.

Comment: okay now i got it :) i was wondering also why arp was showing the internal IP of my router and not the internal IP of the computer I use. Thanks!